# keep looping when clicking cancel and exit button

Tags: vba

i am trying to do a input box loop if it is empty , but it will face problem such as clicked cancel and exit button will also show the same result and keep looping.

```
Dim x As Variant



 Do
      x = InputBox("Please Input Yor  ID!")

       If x <> "" Then Exit Do
       MsgBox "ID cannot be Empty!"

Loop
     MsgBox ("id : " & x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoopInputBox()
    Dim x As Variant
    Do
        DoEvents
        x = Application.InputBox("Please Input Yor  ID!")

        If TypeName(x) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub

    Loop While x = vbNullString

    MsgBox ("id : " & x)
End Sub
```

This idea was taken from [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/3/26/loop-input-box-until-receives-correct-valid-entry).